# Pass any type of list to another class

Tags: c#

I'm building a dynamic search form and I want to send a list to the search form class (any type of list). I've searched here and i didn't find any answer.

### First Class:

```
public class myfirstclass
{
    Search search = new Search(List<anyType>);
    search.show()
}
```

### search form class:

```
public partial class Search : Form
{
    public search(list<anytype> mylist)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Try using List<Object>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the constructor parameter to accept an `IList` instead:

```
List<Foo> somelist = new List<Foo>();
Search search = new Search(somelist);

public partial class Search : Form
{
    public Search(IList mylist)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: error : Error 1 Using the generic type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<T>' requires 1 type arguments

Comment: @OmriTurgeman The code I posted compiles just fine. Make sure you're using `IList` instead of `IList<T>`. You might have to add `using System.Collections` to the top of the file.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [generic class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sz6zd40f.aspx)

```
public partial class Search<T> : Form
{
    public Search(List<T> mylist)
    {
    }
}
```

And you'll need to update the designer class too.

Search.designer.cs

```
partial class Search<T>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Windows Form Designer generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        // code
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: its give me this error : The name 'InitializeComponent' does not exist in the current context

Comment: @OmriTurgeman you likely need to change the class definition in Search.designer.cs to be generic as well.  Updated to include sample